# My Android Application is Not Visible on Google Play Store Search, althought its published

Tags: android

few days ago i have uploaded my application on google play store and it got approved and published but its not visible or available on google play store search results, i just get blank page result, where i can see my application is published and is available on this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.baryalitobkhabar

but not sure why its not visible on play store search result?

any idea?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

When I click your play store link it tells me I have no compatible devices even though I have 10+ modern devices connected to the account I'm on. Apps which are not compatible with your device(s) will not show up in search.

To find the reason you have to review the AndroidManifest.xml in your app and the Release Management section in the Google Play Console.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, what do i have to CHANGE on release management? and what exactly should i change on AndroidManifest.xml? any heads up?

Comment: I can't answer that for you because I can't see what your settings are. It could be anything, e.g. OpenGL version, screen size, localization. Just read the manifest and click through all the settings in Release Management and ask yourself "Would this prevent a Samsung Galaxy S7 in the Netherlands from being eligible to install my app?" (which is one of my devices and my localization). When looking at the manifest make sure you click on the merged manifest tab in Android Studio, it could be the manifest of a library.

Comment: thank you for your answer, what i have got from your first answer is that i went to google release management for the app and i found that it was only available for one country the rest was unavailable, so i ticked for all 147 countries lets see if this helps to find the application on the google play search, although it will take some time to get the updates hopefully this should help to find it thorough search option.

Comment: It may take a couple of hours before it actually starts showing up in search.